# Get document by index position in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with Elasticsearch and I am getting a query error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'script score query returned an invalid score: NaN for doc: 32894')
```

It seems like my metric is returning NaN for document 32894 (`NaN for doc: 32894`). Naturally, the next step is to look at that document to see if there is anything wrong with it.

The problem is that I upload my documents using my own ID, so "32894" is meaningless for me.

A query like

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/_doc/one_of_my_ids?pretty&pretty"
```

works fine, but this fails if I try with the doc number from the error message.

I expected this to be trivial, but some Google has failed to help.

How can I then find this document? Or is using my own IDs not recommended and the unfixable source of this problem?

**Edit**: as requested, this is the query that fails. Note that obviously fixing this is my ultimate goal, but not the specific point of this question. Help appreciated in either case.

I am using the elasticsearch library in Python.

```
self.es.search(index=my_index, body=query_body, size=number_results)
```

With

```
query_body = {
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilaritySparse(params.queryVector, doc['embedding']) + 10.0",
                "params": {"queryVector": query_vector}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the query that fails

Comment: Ok, will do, but that is not really important, at this point I am fine with the query failing, I just need to look at the document that produced the error!

Comment: Are you using some function_score on your query?

Comment: yes, I am using cosineSimilaritySparse

Comment: What the value for doc['embedding'] on the doc that fails, and on a doc that works?

Comment: Well, that's my problem really! I want to see that, but my document index does not match the document number in the error message, so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Not sure how's the syntax on painless, but you can check if your cosineSimilaritySparse returns a NaN and set the score manually to 999999999. Your failing document(s) will be the first. I'm searching for it.

Comment: @Pablo did you manage to get this resolved? I am having the same problem and would appreciate hearing about your solution. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I did. I managed to fix my queries, but I don't think I solved this issue with IDs. I suggest you ask the elastic community, I found it was a bit more helpful for these specific issues. https://discuss.elastic.co/